# war deployment failed in jboss server

Tags: java, web-applications, deployment, jboss, web-deployment

I am deploying war in jboss standalone. it's working. But after some  days i have restarted the server after that war deployment failing with below error

2017-10-04 17:30:46,967 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0183: Service status report
WFLYCTL0184:    New missing/unsatisfied dependencies:
      service jboss.network.management (missing) dependents: [service org.wildfly.network.socket-binding.management-native, service org.wildfly.network.socket-binding.management-https]
      service jboss.network.public (missing) dependents: [service jboss.socket-binding-manager]
      service jboss.remoting.remotingConnectorInfoService.http-remoting-connector (missing) dependents: [service jboss.ejb3.connector]

```
    2017-10-04 17:30:46,928 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([
        ("subsystem" => "datasources"),
        ("data-source" => "konyreportsds")
    ]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0288: One or more services were unable to start due to one or more indirect dependencies not being available." => {
        "Services that were unable to start:" => [
            "org.wildfly.data-source.konyreportsds",
            "jboss.data-source.reference-factory.konyreportsds",
            "jboss.naming.context.java.konyreports",
            "org.wildfly.data-source.konyreportsds"
        ],
        "Services that may be the cause:" => [
            "jboss.network.management",
            "jboss.network.public",
            "jboss.remoting.remotingConnectorInfoService.http-remoting-connector",
            "jboss.network.management",
            "jboss.network.public",
            "jboss.remoting.remotingConnectorInfoService.http-remoting-connector"
        ]
    }}
```

I have goggled it, but i didnt found any solution for this. can some one please let me know what may be the issue?

Comment: Did you get it figured out?

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove war and startup the appserver alone. It seems the problem isn't related to war.

This is probably the cause:

> "data-source" => "konyreportsds"

Maybe that ds is not available anymore, or became unreachable.
Double check modules dependencies, driver and datasource of standalone.xml to be sure.

Comment: Able to access data-source. what is mean of below error

"Services that may be the cause:" => [
     "jboss.network.management",
     "jboss.network.public",
     "jboss.remoting.remotingConnectorInfoService.http-remoting-connector"
    ]

Comment: What has changed that you have access to the data source?

Answer (score 0):

Check your database on which the "konyreportsds" points. Maybe is down? Or your network connection to database is down. Then restart the Wildfly.